# LWC - Calling Javascript method from static resource 3rd party JS file

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

I have following JS file uploaded as static resource in Salesforce.

Static resource utility.zip / utility.js file

```
var x = function (a, b) {return a * b};
```

I would like to call function variable from static resource JS file from LWC component.

```
    import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
    import utility from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/utility';

    export default class lwccomponent extends LightningElement {

     renderedCallback() {

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, utilities + '/utility.js')
        ])
            .then(() => {
                alert('loaded');
                /* how can i call method / function variable from JS file , i am unable to do it. */
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error loading JS file',
                        message: error.message,
                        variant: 'error'
                    })
                );
            });

    }
}
```

my objective is to create a common set of functions to share among components/ project to have to prevent any data issues.

Comment: Can you please explain what kind of problem do you met during achieving your objective?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am unable to see the file in developer tools - network section , meaning file is not getting loaded or unable to call method and it says function in undefined. @kurunve

Comment: You need to make your static resource a module, and not a plain js  -- check similar question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295469/static-javascript-resource-with-lwc

Comment: Thanks @kurunve i checked this question but answer to this i am not looking for, i really wanted to call , method from JS file loaded from static resource no other option.

Comment: agree with Vova. If you want to develop code, that will be shared with lwc components, create lwc service component. Commonly, js is loaded as a static resource for already existed 3-party js libraries. And they must be compatible with locker service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to develop code, that will be shared with lwc components, create lwc service component. Commonly, js is loaded as a static resource for already existed 3-party js libraries, but if you don't have  any options except grouping js code in static resource, your js code should follow the following rule: must explicitly attach library global to `window`

```
window.myLib = (function() {
    return {
        myFunction: function(a, b) {
            return a * b;
        }
    };
}());
```

then you can call it like:

```
loadScript(this, utilities + '/utility.js').then(() => {
    let result = myLib.myFunction(2,2);
});
```

---

you can check rest of requirements for the compatible js library with locker service in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164607/is-there-any-way-to-validate-a-third-party-javascript-library-against-lightning) question

Comment: Thanks @oleksandr-berehovskyi, let me try this and get back to the question. appreciate your response.

Comment: This is just perfect and worked, thanks @oleksandr-berehovskyi for your answer.